# Validar en JQuery un select obteniendo un valor string desde mysql

Tags: php, html, jquery

Les comento, tengo un formulario de registro normal en html, la cosa es que usando el select, quiero cargar el mismo valor (en este caso un select, cuando registro yo selecciono la opcion que quiero) que se almacena en la DB. El id que uso en las opciones  son 1,2,3,etc., por lo que al momento de guardar en la DB solo valido el numero y envio un string al campo que quiero guardar (el tipo de valor que envio a la DB es un string).

Para mostrarles el select seria asi ejemplo:

```
<select class="form-control" name="tipo" id="tipo" required>
    <option value="1">Valor 1</option>
    <option value="2">Valor 1</option>
    <option value="3">Valor 1</option>
</select>
```

Ahora bien, todo normal, yo envio el ajax al php y aqui valido el numero y seteo un string para el campo donde quiero duardarlo, ejemplo:

```
$tipo_aux = isset($_POST["tipo"])? limpiarCadena($_POST["tipo"]):"";

//Valido
if($tipo_aux=="1"){ $tipo="Opcion 1"; }
if($tipo_aux=="2"){ $tipo="Opcion 2"; } //y asi sucesivamente
//Luego aqui llamo la instancia, funcion y envio el objeto.
//Luego todo bien guardado
```

Ahora, la cosa es que como yo uso en los value de las  un numero, cuando yo quiero editar el registro X, el selectpicker no me carga la opcion que esta guardada por defecto, sino que en el formularo de edicion la opcion del select aparece sin seleccionar nada y hay que volver a seleccionarla si queremos hacer alguna edicion de un campo para guardar, ya que sino el formulario me va a validad que ese select no se ha seleccionado nada.

Esta es la funcion javascript que optiene la informacion y setea los id del formulario de edicion, para que carguen la infor correspondiente consultada.

```
function viewItem(id){
    $.post("../ajax/supplier.php?action=show",{id: id}, function(data,status){
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    showForm(true);
    $("#id_1").val(data.Data1); //estos son ejemplos
    $("#id_2").val(data.Data2);
    //aqui cargo mas bla bla blaaa de los campos
    //mas bla bla blaaa .....
    $("#tipo").val(data.Tipo); //Aqui es donde envio al id del select, el
    //valor que quiero cargar pero como el valor en la DB es un string 
    //(varchar) y las opciones tienen un value de tipo 1,2,3,.. no me sale
    //por defecto la que esta guardada, sino que sale sin estar
    //seleccionada, pero si yo lo hago con solo numeros ahi si me sale bien 
    //saleccionada ya que son la misma cadena de valores.
})
}
```

Ahora si alguien me da una mano por favor, alguna sugerencia para no tener que recurrir a almacenar solo numeros y luego mediante el back end estar validando el numero y mostrando otra cosa (si es 1 mostrar tal string) ya que no me gusta mucho.

Saludos.

Comment: Puede que sea porque es temprano o este dormido, pero no me he enterado de anda de lo que dice la pregunta, podrias simplificar en un unas cuantas lines o al menos indicar un poco mas concreto donde esta el error?o sino que es lo que planes conseguir como resultado final??

Comment: Hola Cristian, para contarte que lo solucione refrescando el id del input, que en este caso seria el de el select, pero voy a agregar la solucion para la retroalimntacion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya hace varios dias habia encontrado la solucion y era muy simple, disculpas a los que les robe tiempo, pero bueno, la solucion fue refrescando el id del select mediante el selectpicker.

```
function viewItem(id){
 $.post("../ajax/supplier.php?action=show",{id: id}, function(data,status){
 data = JSON.parse(data);
 showForm(true);
 $("#id_1").val(data.Data1); //estos son ejemplos
 $("#id_2").val(data.Data2);
 //aqui cargo mas bla bla blaaa de los campos
 //mas bla bla blaaa .....
 $("#tipo").val(data.Tipo);
 $('#tipo').selectpicker('refresh'); //Aqui es donde hice la solucion
 //con la misma libreria se puede realizar un refresh y asi queda 
 //seleccionado el id que debe ser
})
}
```

Eso si, esta solucion solo pude encontrarla realizando otra consulta apenas al inicio de la funcion, cuando realizo la funcion de init en el archivo .js, de esta manera llenaba la lista para el input de tipo select iniciara ya lleno, lo que volvia a llenarlo y buscaba el id para seleccionarlo apenas se seleccionaba el valor a editar de toda la fila, asi se mostraba desde el inicio ya seleccionado por aquello que no se editara nada y se presionara guardar.

```
$.post("../ajax/supplier.php?action=listType", function(r) { 
//el parametro 'r' son las opcioes que nos esta devolviendo la funcion ajax de supplier.php
   $("#tipo").html(r);
   $('#tipo').selectpicker('refresh'); 
   //Esto es para obligar a refrescar el id del tipo para que salga al inicio la lista
});
```

Saludos.